TYPO3 12.4.13, ws_scss 12.0.5: css not generated from bootstrap-scss at all
The CSS file is not being generated at all for me!
My configuration is TYPO3 12.4.13, ws_scss 12.0.5, local development with ddev, composer on macOS, and the following TypoScript:
page.includeCSS {
    bootstrap = EXT:mein-sitepackage/Resources/Private/Scss/base-layout.scss
    bootstrap {
        inlineoutput = false
        outputdir = typo3temp/assets/css/
    }
}

Anyone who have a solution?
Tried with inlineoutput both true and false
Tried with outputdir in different pathes, EXT-path, fileadmin-path, ...
Tried with outputfile instead of outputdir, too ...

I was able to see it working using the "outputfile" options...
I start with the dumb questions: is the extension enabled? Clear frontend cache?

I think it´s a problem that you refer to the private folder. Files which are accessible at the frontend ( scss,css,js,... ) must be within public folder e.g. EXT:mein-sitepackage/Resources/Public/Scss/base-layout.scss
